# Trying to create my first React project and running into "Couldn't find the binary scripts" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am starting this react course on udemy: https://www.udemy.com/course/react-redux/learn/lecture/17276262#questions

To create our first project I was instructed to:

- `install node`
- `install create-react-app`
- `npx create-react-app myapp`

I can create the app, but when I try npm/yarn start it throws this error:

```
jsx git:(master) yarn start

yarn run v1.22.4

$ react-scripts start

error Couldn't find the binary react-scripts start

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I think if you use npx there's no reason to install create-react-app, maybe there's a version mismatch between what you installed and what npx is running?

Comment: can you please try to remove node modules and then reinstall them?

Comment: Hi @Dean I know, its being long to get this answers. Though, by any chance do you remember the solution. I am stuck into same. Thanks