# Creating New React App and facing issue "Couldn't find binary"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, binary, node-modules, create-react-app

I have created new react app using `yarn create react-app myapp`

and I am able to create the app but, when I am trying to run it. I am getting this **issue**.

```
  PS C:\Users\MyFolder\Documents\myapp> yarn start   
  yarn run v1.22.11 
  warning ..\..\..\..\package.json: No license field
  $ react-scripts start error Couldn't find the binary react-scripts start
```

**yarn -version**
1.22.11.

**Solution Tried**

Although, it is a new project still it's not working. I tried changing the scripts in `package.json`

```
"start": "node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js start"
 OR
"start": "node node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js"
 OR
"start": "node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js start"
```

and then

```
yarn install
yarn start
```

Though, nothing worked.

I found this [Duplicate Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63599537/trying-to-create-my-first-react-project-and-running-into-couldnt-find-the-bina) but I haven't found answer on that post.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download Visual Studio Code (https://code.visualstudio.com/)
2. Download node.js (https://nodejs.org/en/)
3. npx create-react-app "file name"
4. cd "file name"
5. npm start

react general file structure is ready :))

Comment: Thank you responding. But, I am following the same path with yarn. and reponse is same
******* yarn start
yarn run v1.22.11
warning ..\..\..\package.json: No license field   
$ react-scripts start
error Couldn't find the binary react-scripts startinfo Visit ******

Comment: @UGandhi You're welcome , what exactly do you want to do? ,gökmen.

Comment: I am creating new react app. I just want to run the web-app using "yarn start". I just checked, I have react-script.js file in my node_modules and when, I tried running "$./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start" directly. I am able to open the web-app, but when I am using "yarn start" I am getting binary not found, I mentioned earlier.